# BigDecimal to_s does not match to_f

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bigdecimal

Is the BigDecimal class broken? It seems like the following should never, ever occur:
Note that a.to_f != a.to_s.to_f

> > a.class
> >     => BigDecimal
> >
> > a.to_f
> >     => 18658.1072928
> >
> > a.to_s
> >     => "10865.81072928"
> >
> > b.class
> >     => BigDecimal
> >
> > b.to_f
> >     => 10000.0
> >
> > b.to_s
> >     => "10000.0"
> >
> > (a - b).to_f
> >     => 865.81072928
> >
> > a.to_f - b.to_f
> >     => 8658.1072928

Any ideas as to what might be going wrong? We are running ruby 1.8.7p72 on our servers and 1.8.7p173 on our local machines.

Comment: how and where do you set your a and b variables. ps: no problem with ruby 1.8.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're running Mac OS X 10.6.3 then this might be an explanation: http://www.abletech.co.nz/2010/03/osx-10-6-3-installs-new-ruby-with-faulty-bigdecimal/

To get rid of the problem you could use [RVM](http://rvm.beginrescueend.com/).

Answer (score 0):

As the [docs](http://railsapi.com/doc/ruby-v1.9/classes/BigDecimal.html#M006856) say:

> **to_f**:
>
> Returns a new Float object having approximately the same value as the BigDecimal number. Normal accuracy limits and built-in errors of binary Float arithmetic apply.

That means that Float in ruby behaves just like a float everywhere: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems

Not every number is representable by a Float. In such cases the number is rounded.

Comment: a.to_f => 18658.1072928
a.to_s => "10865.81072928"

I don't think we can blame a difference of almost 8000 on roundoff error...

Comment: You're right. I also tested it on my local machine (I'm running 1.8.7p173 too) and results are different:

    >> a = BigDecimal.new('10865.81072928')
    => #<BigDecimal:101416890,'0.1865810729 28E5',16(20)>
    >> a.to_s
    => "0.186581072928E5"  
    >> a.to_f
    => 18658.1072928

No idea why...